# What is the effect of this python statement?

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, textures

I'm trying to explore the Kivy API and I'm very confused by some code lines I found in their [multitexture example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__canvas__multitexture__py.html).  One line of code seems to assign a value of "1" to a key of "texture0" in "self.canvas", treating "self.canvas" as though it is a python dictionary.

That code is `self.canvas['texture0'] = 1`

However, when I step past this line the debugger, I see no such entry in self.canvas, and self.canvas is of type "RenderContext".  In fact, I see nothing that indicates that the statement changed anything observable in the debugger, but if I evaluate `self.canvas['texture0']`, it evaluates to "1".

[image]

Where is this value being stored?  I also can't find any clues in the Kivy's [canvas docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> treating "self.canvas" as though it is a python dictionary.

This has nothing particularly to do with dictionaries, using the [] notation just calls `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` - see [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). As it happens the class is in this case storing the data in an internal dictionary, but that's an implementation detail, not something required by this syntax.

> However, when I step past this line the debugger, I see no such entry in self.canvas

The canvas objects are defined in cython, and the internal state attributes used for this storage are not visible to the Python code.